# Block disappears in Firefox but not Chrome or Edge

Tags: css, firefox, vertical-alignment

I have a block in a mat-table in Angular that makes a colored square.
When adjusting its height, e.g.

```
 display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 97%;
```

it works well in Chrome and Edge. However, it disappears in Firefox.
Setting the height to px makes it appear, i.e.

```
height: 65px;
```

Setting:

```
-moz-height:100%;
```

for the column class also makes it disappear in Firefox.

It seems that height must be set in Pixels for Firefox using 'height' or it disappears.
Even using:

```
-moz-height: 50px
```

doesn't keep it from disappearing from Firefox if `height` isn't present.

A useful alternative was `em` - it seems that whereas % doesn't work with Firefox - `em` works a bit like % across all browsers.
e.g. `height:4em`

However, the block does not extend vertically as much as it should - and it adds additional size to the row.

There are many instances of Chrome and Firefox rendering height differently, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925879/max-height-ignored-in-firefox-works-in-chrome-and-safari), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532987/heights-rendering-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613898/different-line-height-in-chrome-and-firefox), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359363/height-being-calculated-different-between-chrome-and-firefox), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321664/css-height-is-different-in-different-browser).

Perhaps, the most useful answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532987/heights-rendering-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox) which explains why implementation varies across browsers.

The recommended solutions there are to ensure that parent element height has been set - as I did here:

//for the table

```
  .example-table {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            overflow-y: auto;
            min-width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
    }
```

// for the mat-table in the table

```
 .mat-table {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        display: table;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 100%; 
 }
```

And setting the box-sizing, e.g.:

`-moz-box-sizing:content-box;`  or `-moz-box-sizing:border-box;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Firefox. One issue was that nested divs in any of the columns / cells affected Firefox rendering differently than Chrome and Edge (which worked as predicted).
Removing all nesting where possible helped somewhat. Using the -[`[moz-transform][1]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) methods helped make things more similar across browsers (though not emulating the same behavior).
This helped:

```
.block {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -moz-transform: scaleY(1.2);
        -moz-transform: translateY(5px);
        height: 95%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

where the column is defined as:

```
 td.mat-column-block {
        flex-shrink: 1;
        align-self: stretch;
        vertical-align: center;
        max-width: 50px;
        min-width: 50px; 
        border-top: none;
        height: 50px;
        max-height: 50px;
        min-height: 100%;
        justify-self: stretch;
    }
```